# Android smsManager handling Grave accent character

Tags: android, smsmanager, android-sms

Struck some odd behaviour in my Android sms app when there is a Grave accent in the message, for example; smsTEXT = **"Pls call the office asap if you`re keen."**

Message is within single 160 char sms length, however when I call this;

```
ArrayList<String> segments = smsManager.divideMessage(smsTEXT);
```

the reported number of message parts is greater than 1, in fact 2

```
if (segments.size() > 1 ){
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(etc...)
    nSegments = segments.size();
} else {
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(etc...)
    nSegments = 1;
}
```

`sendMultipartTextMessage` appears to send the message perfectly well (with the Grave accent) in a single part anyway, while in all other respects the app works fine

If I substitute Grave accent with Apostrophe, only a single segment message is reported by size() and one sms sent in a single shot by `sendTextMessage`

If I put several Grave accents in the message, up to 4 segments are reported by size(), although it looks like `sendMultipartTextMessage` only sends one sms

Question: Is there something special about Grave accent in Android `smsManager`..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grave can't be represented by 7 bit ascii (the default for SMS).  This then requires it to be sent as 16 bit characters, which reduces the maximum number of characters by half.  Thus even a short message will require 2 SMSes.  You'll see the same behavior with emojis and other non-ASCII characters.  If you look at sending an SMS in a messaging app like Android's messages that shows the characters remaining in a text, you'll see as soon as you add a non-ASCII character it drops in half (or if placing it in the middle of a text, you'll see the number of texts leap up).

Comment: Thanks @gabe-sechan and well spotted, I had forgotten it wasn't in GSM 7-bit default alphabet, having assumed it was ok due to being an ascii printable character (as used with pagers). That means `divideMessage` must always be called to determine whether to call `sendTextMessage` or `sendMultipartTextMessage` unless such a character is substituted with something else.